# Embed PowerBI report with JavaScript

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm using the PowerBI-Javascript library to embed reports in my website. However, I don't know if it's possible to retrieve this .json file.

> {
>      "type":"report",
>      "accessToken":"flVW00-mB5Lc4fE_ElSgpJ8_7ceL6T_ZL9C_pqbTu4",
>      "id":"c52af8ab-0468-4165-92af-dc39858d66ad",
>      "name":"Retail Analysis",
>      "webUrl":"https://app.powerbi.com/reports/c52af8ab-0468-4165-92af-dc39858d66ad",
>      "embedUrl":"https://embedded.powerbi.com/appTokenReportEmbed?reportId=c52af8ab-0468-4165-92af-dc39858d66ad"
>
> }

In the demo of the library, the report link returns this json which then is used to load the report on the website. In my case I don't have a link that returns a json at all, but just a link to load the report immediately.

I want to know is there a way, for each created report, to generate a link that returns this json. (I'm asking because I'm not in charge of the Power BI report creation, only the website).

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: 
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/dashboards
or
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports

These links can be accessed from Postman with a valid bearer token.